# Show CPU Registers in VS2008 watch window

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cpu-registers, watch

Is it possible to add CPU registers (RAX, EAX, flags, etc etc) with a specific syntax in a watch window so they are displayed like regular variables and printed in base-10 (or hex if Hexadecimal Display is on) ?

e.g:

if Registers window shows RAX = 00000000027A6468,
adding %rax to watch would result in:

```
Name    Value       Type
%rax    41575528    CPU Register
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Pseudovariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164891.aspx)

Comment: Surely qualifies as one of the shortest useful answers on SO. :-)

Comment: sorry, no. Use the register window instead. Note it is removed in Express versions and hidden by default in Pro/Team versions.

Comment: Dang, this doesn't work with the FPU CTRL register.  Any ideas how to "watch" that one?

Comment: I would suggest you to request it on connect.microsoft.com

Comment: This does not work while debugging managed c# code, only native code (this is documented in the linked page).

Answer (score 0):

With VS2010 and higher there is a 'Registers' window (Debug->Windows->Registers). To see the flags and more registers (eg. MMX/SSE) just right click and enable them by the corresponding check mark since they are not shown by default. Some hints for the flags:

```
Overflow    OV        Direction   UP
Interrupt   EI        Sign        PL
Zero        ZR        Aux Carry   AC
Parity      PE        Carry       CY
```

Comment: Also for VS2008! FYI: The menu entry will only whow up while debugging.